# Why can partial derivatives be calculated by keeping other variables constant?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I understand that the partial derivative with respect to $x$ for a function $f(x,y)$ is represented by $f'((x,y);\vec i)$. In this case, we can calculate it by letting $g(t) = f((x,y)+t\vec i;\vec i$), finding $g'(t)$ and then setting $t=0$. Why is it that we can also calculate this partial derivative by considering $y$ as a constant. I know it works, but I am confused as to why.

Comment: Because if $h$ is a function of one variable $x$, differentiating at $x$ is the same as differentiating $t\mapsto h(x+t)$ and evaluating at $t=0$.

Comment: @Max But what confuses me is that we never pay any attention to $x$, we only differentiate with respect to $t$

Comment: Again : differentiating $h$ at $x$ is the same as differentiating $t\mapsto h(x+t)$ at $t=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we want to evaluate $f'((x,y);\vec \imath)$ at the arbitrary point 
$(x_0,y_0).$
Or more succinctly, we want to evaluate $f'((x_0,y_0);\vec \imath),$
where $(x_0,y_0)$ is an arbitrary point.
While we are evaluating this derivative, naturally the values of $x_0$ and $y_0$ do not change, so effectively they are constants during that evaluation.

So now to find $f'((x_0,y_0);\vec \imath)$
your method says to evaluate $g'(t)$
where $g(t) = f((x_0,y_0)+t\vec \imath).$
But note that $(x_0,y_0)+t\vec \imath = (x_0 + t, y_0).$
So we can just as well write $g(t) = f(x_0 + t,y_0).$

But let's take this one step farther. 
Let's make a change of variables: introduce the variable $x$ where $x = x_0 + t.$
Then we can define a function $h$ such that 
$h(x) = f(x,y_0) = f(x_0 + t,y_0) = g(t).$

Now we can use a little single-variable calculus.
In particular, the chain rule with $p(t) = x_0 + t$ tells us that
$$ \frac{d}{dt}h(x) = \frac{d}{dt}h(p(t)) = h'(p(t)) \, p'(t)
= h'(p(t)) = h'(x),
$$

and therefore
$$g'(t) = \frac{d}{dt}g(t) = \frac{d}{dt}h(x) = h'(x) .$$

So to get $g'(t)$ you can evaluate $h'(x).$
But $h'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}f(x,y_0),$
that is, it's what you get if you hold the second argument of $f$ constant, effectively giving you a single-variable function over the first argument, and differentiate with respect to the first argument.

---

I think in fact the idea of differentiating as a function of one of the arguments while holding the other arguments constant is the older, more established way of defining partial derivatives, and the definition by means of a directional derivative is a relatively new idea. So perhaps we should be trying to prove that "we can also calculate"
the old-style partial derivative using the definition you learned!
But I think you can easily enough reverse the steps I took above.

Answer (score 1):

If $g(x,y)$ denotes the partial derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$, then by definition
$$
f(x+\epsilon,y)=f(x,y)+\epsilon \cdot g(x,y) + o(\epsilon).
$$
Note that $y$ is not changed at all in this equation, only $x$. Thus, we can ignore $y$ (more precisely, hold it constant) when taking the partial derivative with respect to $x$.

In other words, if we consider a constant $c$ and substitute the constant $y=c$ into the function $f(x,y)$ to obtain a new function $h(x)=f(x,c)$ then $h'(x)=g(x,c)$.

Comment: How do you get to $f(x+\epsilon,y)=f(x,y)+\epsilon \cdot g(x,y) + o(\epsilon)$ "by definition"? The definition of partial derivative that I was given is that it is the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $e_k$ where $e_k$ are the unit coordinate vectors.

Comment: Also, what is $o$?

Comment: Little o is defined here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Comment: If you "solve" for the little o in my equation, you get $o(\epsilon)=\frac{f(x+\epsilon,y)-f(x,y)}{\epsilon}-g(x,y)$. Saying that it is little o of $\epsilon$ is equvalent to saying that $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}|\frac{f(x+\epsilon,y)-f(x,y)}{\epsilon}-g(x,y)|=0$. That should resemble the definition here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative#Formal_definition a little closer. In essence little o$(\epsilon)$ is a shorthand for any quantity that is much smaller than $\epsilon$ in the limit as $\epsilon\to 0$.